# Break apart an array in PHP - Convert to String

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$arr['alpha'] = 'a';
$arr['beta'] = 'b';
$arr['delta'] = 'd';
```

Does anyone know if PHP has a function to take the above array and produce:

`$some_string` -- where $some_sting is set to the associative values of the array such that if I echoed $some_sting I would see:

"a,b,d"

Thanks.

I know how to write a for loop to produce the result, but I am curious if there is a simple function that already does this.

Comment: Ok, the answers below are correct, but actually I stated the wrong outcome I am looking for. I actually want to yield "alpha,beta,delta". Is that possible?

Comment: You can use `array_keys` to get an array of the keys, and then implode that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Update:

About your comment under FreekOne's answer you wrote:

> Ok, the answers herein are correct, but actually I stated the wrong outcome I am looking for. I actually want to yield "alpha,beta,delta". Is that possible?

This is how you do that..

```
<?php
function implode_key($glue = "", $pieces = array()) {
    $arrK = array_keys($pieces);
    return implode($glue, $arrK);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$some_string = implode(',',$arr);  //a,b,d`

`$some_string = implode(',',array_keys($arr));  //alpha,beta,delta`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's implode function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Prototype:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

So you could do this:

```
$glued = implode(',' , $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, `join()` can also be used, but it's nothing more than an alias of the already suggested `implode()`.

So, doing an `echo join(',',$arr);` would output `a,b,c` as well.

Comment: PHP has way too much aliases.. `implode()` vs `explode()` makes sense to me, but `join()` vs `explode()` ?? (since there ain't an `unjoin()` function or something like that..).. I know.. slightly offtopic.

Comment: @Enrico: agreed, but I'm not the one who threw all these aliases in PHP :P I just got used to `join()` because it's shorter, I guess, although the difference is obviously negligible.

Comment: The opposite of `join` is `split`, like in the Python camp. As nice as it is to accommodate for varying backgrounds, I agree that consistency is probably better - and don't detach this statement from the current context.

Comment: @FreelOne No worries.. I didn't mean to say that you created those aliases :p @erisco, thanks.. amazing how much I learn by answering other people's questions :p

Comment: Ok, the answers herein are correct, but actually I stated the wrong outcome I am looking for. I actually want to yield "alpha,beta,delta". Is that possible?

Comment: @Dr. DOT: not unless the values in the array that's being imploded are "alpha", "beta", "delta" to begin with.